# Is there any command-line software to create e-books from the scratch in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, ebooks

I would like to automate e-book build from remote repositories. A command-line tool would be useful in this case. Is there any software for Ubuntu?

Comment: Sure, you could use LaTeX  `latex`. I would use an editor like TexStudio, or TexWorks, but if you want to use the command line, go for it/

Comment: Is LaTeX suitable to output `.mobi`, `.aw3`, `.epub`, etc files?

Comment: I know nothing about proprietary file formats. latex will make a variety of document types however, and if it can be converted from PostScript, latex can make it.

Comment: Could be relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub.

Comment: I think e-books can't be converted from postscript or pdf... maybe I should make it clearly in the title that those e-books are for being used in e-readers like Kindle, Kobo, Nook, etc

Comment: I want a software which can build e-books from its sources. If I convert, all possibilities of configuring fonts, size of fonts and the page in e-readers are lost...

Comment: _"If I convert, all possibilities of configuring fonts, size of fonts and the page in e-readers are lost"_  That is not true.  For an example, see [this](http://www.indiesunlimited.com/2014/08/08/a-quick-and-dirty-ebook-with-calibre/)

Comment: @John1024 Yes, you're right, but my experience converting from pdf shows me the result isn't good enough. A better approach is editing e-book source and building it. Final results are more predictable this way.

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto You are right that conversion from PDF to ebook is _just awful_.  But, epub is largely just a compressed form of HTML.  So, converting from HTML, or other similar formats, to an ebook works well.

Comment: I use Sigil. It's not a command line tool, but an editor: https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A wide variety of documents can be converted to ebook (epub, mobi, ...) using `ebook-convert` which is part of the `calibre` package.

For example, as long as `input` is a supported format, an `epub` can be created with the command:

```
ebook-convert  input output.epub
```

Or, if you use kindles:

```
ebook-convert  input output.mobi
```

Some input formats include:  LIT, MOBI, AZW, EPUB, AZW3, FB2, DOCX, HTML, PRC, ODT, RTF, PDB, TXT, PDF.

If the input file is a PDF, then one may want to add an option:

```
ebook-convert --enable-heuristics  input.pdf output.epub
```

Calibre may be available from your package manager but it often helps to install the latest version which is available [here](https://calibre-ebook.com/download).

#### Authoring a book

As an alternative to calibre, OpenOffice/LibreOffice offers an extension, Writer2ePub, to claims to be able to create "well formatted, easy readable ePub" files with a single click.

The Writer2ePub extension can be downloaded from [here](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/writer2epub).

Comment: I don't want to convert, I need a command-line software which can build the e-book from its source.

Comment: It's like a markup language: http://www.jedisaber.com/eBooks/formatsource.shtml

Comment: That markup language is a subset of HTML.  Calibre works well with HTML.

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto By the way, that is a nice tutorial.  It begins with html (part 1) and ends with zipping the files up into an epub (part 3).  How close are your sources to the final format?

Comment: Pure text and images... Still thinking how to assemble everything LOL

Comment: OK.  You will likely want to add some markup to indicate chapter headings and image locations and such.  If you are a perfectionist, that jedisaber tutorial is ideal: it allows you to have total control over the output. If you want some convenience, you may be satisfied with using a word processor or html editor of your choice and then trust in calibre or pandoc to handle the rest.  After the conversion, you can edit the ebook with calibre to do some fine tuning.

Comment: Yeap! This could be a good approach! thx!

Comment: Have you used OpenOffice/LibreOffice?  Calibre and Pandoc claim to be able to convert their files to epub.  Also, there is a `Writer2ePub` extension that claims to enable OpenOffice/LibreOffice to create epub directly.

Answer (score 11):

The software `pandoc` ( http://pandoc.org/ ) might come in handy for your needs. It can be installed in Ubuntu by opening a terminal (Alt-Ctrl-T) and typing `sudo apt install pandoc`.

Pandoc can convert between a variety of different formats, including txt,  **html**, xhtml, doc, docx, odt, **epub**, **fb2**, docbook, OPML, LaTeX, **pdf**, markdown, asciidoc, MediaWiki, Dokuwiki, org-mode, and a variety of others.

It does not appear to support conversion to/from mobi or aw3, but could certainly build an epub file from a variety of different sources. Then if you like the epub file it produces, you could use @John1024 's answer to convert to mobi or kindle format.

By starting with a source file that supports formatting, such as markdown, html, asciidoc, or the like, you can get a nicely-formatted epub output. The [pandoc README file](http://pandoc.org/README.html) gives a nice overview of the command-line options that are available (including options for table of contents, fonts, link styles, margins, etc).

Comment: Pandoc does show an example on its site of how to build an EPUB of moderate complexity using it.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat is referring to the how to make an epub with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/epub.html) example.